# Foreign key Integrity constraint violation: 1452

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I've recently started trying to use foreign keys to make database management easier on myself. I'm having a terrible time trying to figure out how they actually work, and most of the time I can get it working between tables without issue. But I'm currently having an issue with 2 of my tables, and I can't figure it out.

I'm getting an error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
>   update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`REDACTED`.`rc_logs`, CONSTRAINT `rc_logs_ibfk_1` FOREIGN
>   KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `rc_teammates` (`uid`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON
>   UPDATE CASCADE)
>   [/home5/redacted/public_html/redacted/rc/public/assets/php/connection.php:25]

but my tables seem to be set up properly, and I'm really confused about why it's not working. Here is my table structures:

**rc_teammates**

```
CREATE TABLE `rc_teammates` (
  `uid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` text NOT NULL,
  `primary_line` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `hireStatus` text NOT NULL,
  `created_on` date NOT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE `rc_teammates`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`uid`), ADD UNIQUE KEY `uid` (`uid`), ADD KEY `primary_line` (`primary_line`), ADD KEY `primary_line_2` (`primary_line`);

ALTER TABLE `rc_teammates`
  MODIFY `uid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

ALTER TABLE `rc_teammates`
ADD CONSTRAINT `rc_teammates_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`primary_line`) REFERENCES `rc_lines` (`uid`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

**rc_logs**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `rc_logs` (
  `uid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `line` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `timein` time NOT NULL,
  `timeout` time NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=53 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE `rc_logs`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`uid`), ADD KEY `user_id` (`user_id`), ADD KEY `line` (`line`), ADD KEY `user_id_2` (`user_id`);

ALTER TABLE `rc_logs`
  MODIFY `uid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=53;
ALTER TABLE `rc_logs`
ADD CONSTRAINT `rc_logs_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `rc_teammates` (`uid`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
ADD CONSTRAINT `rc_logs_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`line`) REFERENCES `rc_lines` (`uid`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

I've tried to look up the error, and I've had this issue before but I do not remember how I solved it. What's worse is, this was working earlier, until I emptied the rc_teammates table to start fresh.

I really cannot figure this out, and would love any pointers. Thanks!

Comment: hi. you might have data in the rc_logs table with user_id entries that don't exist in the rc_teammates table? (I assume you already have data, due to the auto_increment offset)

Comment: try something like this to find entries that violate the foreign key: `select rc_logs.uid,rc_logs.user_id,rc_teammates.uid from rc_logs left join rc_teammates on rc_logs.user_id=rc_teammates.uid having rc_teammates.uid is null;`

Comment: @Ossip I think that I emptied the data out incorrectly. I'm not at able to get to my computer right now so I will be looking into this soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said you have "emptied" (`TRUNCATE`?) the table `rc_teammates`.
And you try to insert a record in `rc_logs`, and this record has a `user_id` that doesn't exists in `rc_teammates`, thus violation of the following constraint:

```
ADD CONSTRAINT `rc_logs_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `rc_teammates` (`uid`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

Just add a record in `rc_teammates`, having a `uid` equal to the `user_id` of the record you are trying  to insert in `rc_logs`, and retry.

---

Also, about this :

```
ALTER TABLE `rc_teammates`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`uid`), ADD UNIQUE KEY `uid` (`uid`),

ALTER TABLE `rc_teammates`
  MODIFY `uid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

When you set a column as `PRIMARY KEY`, it is de facto : `UNIQUE`, `NOT NULL` and `INDEXED`. You don't need to specify all this, PRIMARY KEY is enough. This is valid for your other table as well.

Comment: Actually what I did was selected all the rows and deleted them. I think it started with a foreign key error when I tried to truncate so I did it as a workaround

Comment: It turns out it broke when I sorted my data array using `asort`, it reset the array indexes which were the keys to my teammates. I fixed this by switching to `uasort`, which keeps the same indexes. That was such a headache x.x